# Multithreading inside an EJB/MDB

Tags: jakarta-ee, ms-access, ejb, java.util.concurrent

Is there a way to run multiple threads inside a single EJB execution?

What I'm trying to do is essentially an ETL process: the `onMessage` method of an MDB (`@MessageDriven`) will run a query, then kick off multiple threads to insert rows into some target table (all native JDBC, not JPA.)

It could just as easily be a `@Stateless` session bean as well.

The question is - Can you use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` inside an EJB?  Even if it's not strictly legal according to spec, can you get away with it if the background threads are not accessing any Java EE / container-managed resources?

If not, is there a better way to do this?  I know about `@Async` but would lose control over the number of allowed threads per job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, yes, you can use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` inside an EJB.  The EJB spec puts limits on what an EJB can do because it can cause problems for either Java EE services (non-issue for your situation) and for the resources consumed by the server itself.  You'll need to be careful with the latter by somehow ensuring that if you get a "storm" of MDB activity that you don't end up creating more threads than the JVM can handle.